# Where is the Mindstorms module files stored

Tags: python, lego-mindstorms

I would like to find out where the source code for the `mindstorms` module is for the Mindstorms Robot Inventor.

At the start of each file there is a starting header of

```
from Mindstorms import ...
Etc..
```

That is what I want to find.

I have tryed multiple python methods to file the file path, but they all return `./projects/8472.py`

Thanks,
henos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting file path of imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729583/getting-file-path-of-imported-module)

Comment: No, sorry, it just returns `mindstorms/__init__.mpy`

Comment: No file path before

Comment: I am thinking that the code is stored on the hub, not locally on my device

Answer (score 1):

You've likely been using `__file__` and similar, correct? Yes, that will give you the *currently running file*, but since you can't edit the code for the actual Mindstorms code, it's not helpful. Instead, you want to inspect the directory itself, like you would if your regular Python code were accessing a data file elsewhere.

Most of the internal systems are `.mpy` files (see http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.12/reference/mpyfiles.html), so directly reading the code from the device is less than optimal. Additionally, this means that many "standard library" packages are missing or incomplete; you can't `import pathlib` but you can `import os`, but you can't use `os.walk()`. Those restrictions make any sort of directory traversal a little more frustrating, but not impossible.

For instance, the file `runtime/extensions.music.mpy` looks like the following (note: not copy-pasted since the application doesn't let you):

```
M☐☐☐ ☐☐☐
 ☐6runtime/extensions/music.py ☐☐"AbstractExtensions*☐☐$abstract_extension☐☐☐☐YT2 ☐☐MusicExtension☐☐4☐☐☐Qc ☐|
☐☐ ☐ ☐☐ ☐☐☐☐ ☐2 ☐☐play_drum2☐☐☐play_noteQc ☐d:
☐☐ *☐☐_call_sync#☐,☐+/-☐☐drumb6☐YQc☐  ☐☐drum_nos☐musicExtension.playDrum☐☐E☐
☐      *☐     #☐,☐+/-☐☐instrumentb*☐☐noteb*☐☐durationb6☐YQc☐  ☐☐☐☐s☐musicExtension.playNote
```

Sure, you can *kind of* see what's going on, but it isn't that helpful.

You'll want to use combinations of `os.listdir` and `print` here, since the MicroPython implementation doesn't give access to `os.walk`. Example code to get you started:

```py
import os
import sys

print(os.uname())  # note: doesn't reflect actual OS version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64449448/how-to-import-from-custom-python-modules-on-new-lego-mindstorms-robot-inventor#comment115866177_64508469

print(os.listdir("."))  # ['util', 'projects', 'runtime', ...]
print(os.listdir("runtime/extenstions"))  # ['__init__.mpy', 'abstract_extension.mpy', ...]

with open("runtime/extensions/music/mpy", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)

sys.exit()
```

Again, the lack of copy-paste from the console is rough, so even when you do get to the "show contents of the file on screen" part, it's not that helpful.

One cool thing to note though is that if you load up a scratch program, you can read the code in regular `.py`. It's about as intelligible as you'd expect, since it uses *very* low-level calls and abstractions, not the `hub.light_matrix.show_image("CLOCK6")` that you'd normally write.

Comment: If you're interested in just seeing the current directory structure (as of 2.1.4-mindstorms.13), https://gitlab.com/mmoran0032/mindstorms/-/blob/main/mindstorms/tree.md

Comment: i get a os error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "programrunner/__init__.py", line 1, in start_program
File "./projects/53995.py", line 11
OSError: [Errno 2] ENOENT
```
(that is a direct copy/paste of ur code)

Comment: wait, nvm, typo

Comment: and also, i was wondering if the files were stored locally on the hub, not on my device

Comment: but i cant seem to access it using the usb port

Comment: You can attempt decoding it, but it may still be unintelligible since it’s not written like normal Python. I’ve only worked minimally with embedded systems in Python, so you should check out the documentation for MicroPython to learn more.